# Additional debug option for runnable jar using command prompt

Tags: java, debugging, jar

I know that the `java -jar filename.jar` is used for executing the jar file using command prompt, but could anyone please explain the following command:

```
java -jar filename.jar -debug
```

What is the exact use of the `-debug` in the above command?

Answer (score 1):

This is not a flag for the Java Interpreter (as those should be passed **before** the actual class/jar).

If you execute the command-line you posted above, this will launch your `filename.jar`-files main class and give it's `main(String[] args)`-method the `-debug`-parameter as the second argument in the `args`-array.

---

But, there is (or was) also the `-debug` flag from older Java versions, which has been replaced by the [`-Xdebug` flag](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/java/). The (certainly old) [manpage](http://amath.colorado.edu/computing/software/man/java.html) states that:

> **-debug**         Allows the Java debugger - jdb(1) - to attach
>                       itself  to  this java session. When -debug is
>                       specified on the command line java displays a
>                       password  that must be used when starting the
>                       debugging session.

If a Java application is launched with the debug flag, remote-debuggers can attach to the running application and you can (for example) monitor it using [JConsole](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/management/jconsole.html)